# Delete others' comments on my own post

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments

If you use social media, you may know that all comments others posted on your **own** posts can be deleted by **you** if you see that it is unnecessary.

I know StackExchange is not a social media system, but its format is somewhat the same as social media (there are posts, there are comments, there are up/down-votes (like "Like"/"Dislike"), there is even chat). So **I think it is good if we can delete comments on my own post**.

Some of the comments recently posted on my posts are very looooong and not useful at all. That is why I want this feature.

Comment: Why don't you flag them as 'It's no longer needed.'?

Comment: This seems like an awesome way to silence criticism or other unwanted speech on your post.  Don't like it?  Delete it!

Comment: @fbueckert No, I am always looking for such criticism, not denying them. Look at my comment on Glorfindel's answer. :)

Comment: *You* wouldn't delete it.  But *others* absolutely would.  Feature requests need to be vetted for general use, not just good faith.

Comment: The current method of flagging gets a moderator involved to reduce possible hard feelings between you and the person making the comment. Because of that, I think it is best not to have this ability. I did not down-vote (nor up-vote) your question.

Comment: If this would be implemented it would be the first time anyone else except the OP or a mod can remove a contribution unilateral (except for a few corner cases). These kind of changes are so fundamental that it would need lots of real evidence and prove that such feature would be beneficial overall to the communities of all sites in the SE network. Just a hunch that it is a good idea is not enough to convince me.

Comment: **This feature already exists**. If you flag a comment and it contains certain *trigger words* it is automatically deleted when flagged by only one person.

Comment: @MEEisJohannGambolputty... But that’s not related to being the owner of the post.

Comment: @Alex yes. The OP stated in the comments though that they would be interested in this feature in order to be able to remove chatty, unneccessary comments. This is exactly the same usecase as the one of the feature outlined in my prior comment

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If there's something wrong with an answer of yours, I can downvote it, but that doesn't tell future visitors why it's wrong. I can leave a comment in addition (or even instead of downvoting) which is more useful.

Now, if you disagree with my comment and this feature request would be implemented, you could simply delete my comment. I think that's a very bad idea.

If a comment really bothers you, just flag it for moderator attention and explain why you feel bothered. It might depend on the site you're on, but on most sites comments which do not help improving the post are simply deleted.

Comment: I never delete complaining comments/feedback comments but really appreciated them. Only that there are some comments on my post which is chit-chat, spam, or comments attacking others, etc, which I think should be directly deleted.

Comment: @joule_voo I think it's great that *you* wouldn't use this feature in an abusive way. Unfortunately, we have to consider the users who would. As such, we're going to encourage you to use the system as it's currently implemented - flag comments that you don't think need to be on your post and let the moderators handle it.

Comment: The problem is the system is not able to distinguish between your proposed use case and potential abuse. That's why we have human exception handlers aka moderators.

Comment: But people don't READ the questions...they visually SCAN them. And...by scanning & not reading...they often miss the very portion of the question that addresses their "comment". As a result, the comment section fills with irrelevant banter...that muddies the "comment section" for readers later-on. This very thing happened to me today. In truth...I have found...no amount of "clarifying" can replace READING versus SCANNING a question.  So I would LOVE to be able to delete the banter.